# Is it possible/how can I run up to 18 .devcontainers at the same time, all with individual ruby versions/node versions?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

According to the advanced documentation on Microsofts website here https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/configure-separate-containers

It sounds like its not possible to do what im desiring (or at least not easily)

we are a nodejs shop, but have lots of legacy apps that are actively maintained in ruby

My real work dev environment runs up to 18 individual apps running on their own ports, usually only 5-10 of them are running at the same time in development, but for the apps written in ruby thanks to RVM we use many different ruby versions for our production apps

```
$ rvm list
ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.9 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

NodeJS apps and wep apps running in the browser all share the same node version `v16.15.0`

Is it possible to specify a `.devcontainer` folder for each app and run all my apps at the same time within containers? or are devcontainers meant to be ran one at a time?

It seems like if I follow the documentation that I have to move all the apps into individual subfolders by ruby version with a dockerfile per ruby version -- this seems like it will fall apart when I run git commits, because the apps themselves are stored to git, not ruby versions, and my team will lose out on the shared dockerfiles between projects

Comment: Can you standardize on just two Ruby versions?  A Dockerfile isn't very large or complex (an individual project's Gemfile is probably bigger), what's wrong with creating a separate Dockerfile per project?

Comment: its mainly a VSCode question, docker can certainly support running a separate Dockerfile per project, but VSCode has plugin support that microsoft has added to run each your apps in devcontainers, which takes all your VSCode plugins and spins them up in a container, allowing you to make live edits to files that map to the container and obtain a more uniform dev environment regardless of OS